# Oracle SQL Alphabetic Patern Recognition

Tags: sql, oracle, design-patterns

How do I use LIKE or REGEXP_LIKE to only find records where the first 5 characters are alphabetic (A-Za-z) only?  I've tried several different attempts without success, including trying to include a 5 character substring.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE sourcecode LIKE ????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular expression is going to cover **UPPER CASE** and **LOWER CASE** both alphabets. Try (Enclosed it in quotes whatever you like):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (sourcecode, '^[a-zA-Z]{5}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_LIKE`.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (sourcecode, '^[a-z]{5}')
```